# Problem when resizing an array of structs and writing/reading it to a binary file

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, binaryfiles

After creating more than 8 users the array size doubles but then when it writes it back to the binary file something goes wrong and on the next run of the program the read function does not work
the code is for university assignment so icant use vectors, strings, classess and i cant change the user struct

I tried multiple falues for currMax but when it reaches it the read/write functions dont run corrrectly

Comment: You should ask your money back. This is a terrible way to learn C++

Comment: What is your actual assignment or exercise? What are its requirements and limitations? Why are you doing your own memory handling? Why are you using C-style null-terminated strings?

Comment: You must be taking a very advanced C++ course, since you cannot use C++ bread-and-butter vectors and strings, but instead have to work with close-to-the-metal details, C-style char array strings, C-style string APIs, and manual memory management.

Comment: Slightly more constructive: let's say your `readUsers` function reads 500 as `numberOfUsers`. Where in that function do you make room for 500 users in your `Users` object?

Comment: What is `generateIdUser`?. BTW the `#include`s and `using namespace std;` are missing. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Botje in the function initUser when numberOfUsers is equal to half of the currMax I resize the array so that it never reaches the end

Comment: Well you probbaly can fix this code, but the overall approach is overly complicated. Furthermore you should probably use `std::vector`  and `std::string` for this problem, but maybe they told you not to... It's up to you to [edit] the question and add all requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < users.numberOfUsers; i++)
    {
        file.read((char*)&users.user[i], sizeof(users.user[i]));
    }
```

If you were to start searching your code for the specific line that makes sure that the `users.user` array is at least `user.numberOfUsers` in size, your search will come up empty.

At this point `users`'s default constructor allocated a `user` array whose size is 8. If there are more than 8 records read from the file, this results in undefined behavior.

The shown code  reads `numberOfUsers` and `currMax`, clobbering its contents, but without resizing `user` accordingly to what the new `currMax` says.

There are multiple, other issues with the shown code, this only addresses the issue that was asked.

Comment: thanks for the agressive and fast response i added `users.user = new User[users.currMax]` in the `readUser` function and it now works... on to fixing the next problem!

Comment: Yes: the next problem would be the memory leak that you just created.

Comment: i have a `freeUsers` func

Comment: Your constructor: sets `numberOfUsers` to 0; `currMax` to 8, and allocates `user`. Your `freeUsers`: sets `numberOfUsers` to 0, `currMax to 8`, and deletes `user`. Here's a quiz for you: when `numberOfUsers` is 0, and `currMax` is 8, how do you know whether `user` is allocated, or not?